# Spring Boot. Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement

Tags: java, spring

Подключил приложение к MySQL. Вместо стабильной работы получаю стек ошибок:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table topic (id varchar(255) not null, description varchar(255), name varchar(255), primary key (id)) engine=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:277) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:71) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.vladhuk.springproject.SpringProjectApplication.main(SpringProjectApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:782) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:666) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
```

Как видно, проблема с созданием таблицы. Пробовал гуглить, казалось бы много есть решений, но ни одно мне не подошло.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.vladhuk</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-project</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java_test?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=Europe/Kiev
spring.datasource.username=vladhuk
spring.datasource.password=1
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Topic.java

```
@Entity
public class Topic {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String description;

    public Topic() {}

    public Topic(String id, String name, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    // getters & setters
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я не ошибаюсь, вам нужно изменить значение в **application.properties**
`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create`

и

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false, unique=true)
private Long id;
```

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

у вас `private String id;` MySQL пытается создать ключ varchar(255) кажется по этому он и ругается.
Вот тут подробнее про эту [ошибку](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746207/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-1000-bytes)

Comment: Ставить spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create я пробовал и до этого, но оно ни на что не влияло. А изменив тип id на long, программа заработала. Просто в примере, с которого я взял код, у человека все работало, правда у него бд была другая, так что скорее всего эта проблема касалась непосредственно MySQL.

Comment: @VladislavHukovskii рад что помогло. Если я не ошибаюсь, это ошибка движка `MyISAM` при `InnoDB` такого вроде не должно быть.